# how can "compareTo()" method avoid overflowing?

Tags: java

i heared that i should use compare() method for comparing two objects.
instead of using - (substraction) directly. because -(substraction) can invoke overflow

```
public class Employee implements Comparable<Employee> {
... 
public int compareTo(Employee other) {
    return Double.compare(salary, other.salary);  // don't use (-)
}
```

}

and when i saw this implemented CompareTo() code(in Interger.class)

```
  public static int compare(int x, int y) {
    return (x < y) ? -1 : ((x == y) ? 0 : 1);
}
```

and i could see '>'
but as i know it eventually would be using substraction like in c++... probably in interpreter.. if i'm right
and use this result 0 ,1,-1 as = < >
what's different?
why when i use compareTo() method i can avoid overflowing?
please give me a detail reason.

Comment: *i know it eventually would be using substraction* What do you mean? Why do you think so?

Comment: The thing you aren't supposed to do is `return salary - other.salary;` because that can overflow. Then you show an implementation that **doesn't** do that. So **what** are you asking?

Comment: when i use '<' it would use substraction for compare two objects programmingly. doesn't it?

Comment: i want to know how compare two objects correctly when i use 
comparison operators (> < == )

Comment: Computer-level subtraction will definitely consider overflow...```Integer.MIN_VALUE - 5``` is ```2147483643``` in Java, does the computer think that ```Integer.MIN_VALUE``` is greater than 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in this post, the problem with using subtraction is the following.

> This is due to integer overflow. When thisVal is very large and anotherVal is negative then subtracting the latter from the former yields a result that is bigger than thisVal which may overflow to the negative range.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2728810/9520059

Indeed, the compiler will probably use a subtraction at very low level when evaluating the '<', however, it will check for overflows.

Comment: "_Indeed, the compiler will probably use a subtraction at very low level when evaluating the '<', however, it will check for overflows._": comparing two integer values is such a basic concept that (most/all) modern CPUs have specific instructions for this (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/43844182 for information on the intel x64 architectur)